# Add function to oninput listener using JQuery vs adding it directly to the html tag

Tags: jquery, html, addeventlistener

I'm dynamically appending a range input to the html body:

```
var slider = "<input type='range' min='1' max='100' value='50' class='slider' id='slider_1' oninput='f1()'>";
$('body').append(slider);
```

On each input, the function `f1()` should fire, e.g.

```
function f1(){
  console.log('fired');
}
```

With the code above, `f1()` fires each time the input is changed - just what I want.

However, the `oninput` function needs some parameters that are established later, so I want to add it programmatically like:

```
$("#slider_1").oninput = f1();
```

If I do this, `f1()` only fires once and not with every input.

Why is this and how can I change it?

Comment: The jQuery syntax for adding a listener is `$(selector).input(callback)`. In general, jQuery doesn't use property assignments, it does everything with functions.

Comment: Actually a slighlty different solution does the job (wasn't specifying that I use JQuery > 1.8): `$("#slider_1").on('input', function() {...}`. Didn't know that the other solutions are outdated. Thanks for pointing me into that direction.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that the `input` event doesn't have a shortcut method like `click` does.